# SSD not detected anymore

Tags: boot, ssd, nvme

I bought a [Lenovo Y540 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Lenovo-Legion-Y540-15/p/88GMY501214) and installed two SSD's: a Samsung 860 EVO and a Samsung 970 EVO Plus (M.2 NVMe). I installed Win 10 on the NVMe drive and things were working fine. Both SSDs were listed in the information tab in the boot menu.

After a restart (not the first one) the laptop goes in a "Checking media - failed" loop, meaning it can't find any drive with an OS installed. Now, the info tab in the boot menu only shows the 860 EVO SSD. The NVMe one, with the OS, is not present anymore.

Before the issue occurred (but not sure if right before the latest restart) I've installed the Samsung NVMe driver from their website. I also used Samsung Magician to do some benchmarks on both SSD's (everything ok) and enabled 10% Over-Provisioning on both SSD's. Is there a chance any of these has messed something up ? If not, what could be the issue ?

Comment: Don't bother fixing it, return the laptop and get a good one. Even if you can get it to work now, it may fail later and you'll be risking data loss.

Comment: @K7AAY that was indeed the problem. The drive was like 1.5mm not enough inserted. Now I feel dumb. Regardless, I find it strange how it stopped working after a restart. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove then reseat the m.2 drive and retry.

As the esteemed late Dr. Pournelle said, [90% of problems are cables and connectors](https://www.jerrypournelle.com/chaosmanor/pournelles-law/).